# How to enable and auto fill date fields based on start date, number of days and end date using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I enable and auto fill the consecutives dates in date fields based on the Inputs in `start date`,`Number of days` and `end date`? I have 9 date fields (`date2`--`date10`) and I want to auto-fill the dates as per user Inputs in `Number of days`.

**For example**: If user inputs `start date- 03/10/2020` and `number of days- 5` and then `end-date` should be - `08/10/2020`.
And the other 9 date fields should display like :

```
day2- 04/10/2020,
day3- 05/10/2020,
day4- 06/10/2020,
day5- 07/10/2020,
day6- 08/10/2020,
day7- disabled,
day8- disabled,
day9- disabled,
day10- disabled
```

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function (num) {
    var value = this.valueOf();
    value += 86400000 * num;
    return new Date(value);
}
$('#n_days').change(function(){
    var $datepicker = $('#start_date');
    var $datepicker1 = $('#end_date');
    
    var selectedDate = $datepicker.val();
    var result = new Date(selectedDate);
    var dateval = result.getDate();
    
    var ndays = $('#n_days').val();
    numdays =  Number(ndays);
    
    var expirationDate = result.addDays(numdays);
    
     end_date1 = new Date(expirationDate);
     var day = ("0" + end_date1.getDate()).slice(-2);
     var month = ("0" + (end_date1.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
     var year = end_date1.getFullYear();
     var newdate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
     $datepicker1.val(newdate);

});
```

```html
 <script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" > 
    </script> 

<div class="container">
 
 <form id="form1" name="form1" action="add_con.php" method="post">
      
 <table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-40">
        <label for="startdate">start date:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-60">
     
        <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" size="20" >
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  
  </tr>
 
 
  <td> <div class="row">
      <div class="col-40">
        <label for="n_daysa">No. of days:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-60">
          <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 12pt">
          <font size="4">
         <input type="number" id="n_days" name="n_days" min=0 placeholder="Enter no. of days.." required size="20" style="font-size:14px"></font>
       </font>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-40">
        <label for="end_datea">&nbsp;end date:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-60">
           <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 12pt">
          <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="End date.." required size="20" style="font-size:14px">
          </font>

      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

</table>
 <br><br><br>
 <hr color="#003399">

  
<!-- start second table-->

<table class="table1" style="width:1209;" height="151">
  <tr>
    <th height="21" width="34"><font color="#003399">Day</font></th>
    <th height="21" width="295"><font color="#003399">Date</font></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="1" width="34"><b>2</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date2" name="date2" size="10" style="width: 90%; "></font></td>
    </tr>
  
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>3</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date3" name="date3" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>4</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date4" name="date4" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>5</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date5" name="date5" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>6</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date6" name="date6" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>7</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date7" name="date7" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>8</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date8" name="date8" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>9</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date9" name="date9" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>10</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date10" name="date10" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
</table>


<!-- end second table -->

    <div class="row">
      <p align="center">
      <font face="Cambria">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></font>

      <font face="Cambria">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"> </font>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added to your already existing function to populate end date field.  Run the for loop and keep adding one day to your start date.  If it is less than or equal to the end date, populate the relevant date field. Otherwise disable that date field.

```
<script>
Date.prototype.addDays = function (num) {
    var value = this.valueOf();
    value += 86400000 * num;
    return new Date(value);
}
$('#n_days').on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var $datepicker = $('#start_date');
    var $datepicker1 = $('#end_date');

    var selectedDate = $datepicker.val();
    var result = new Date(selectedDate);
    var dateval = result.getDate();

    var ndays = $('#n_days').val();
    numdays =  Number(ndays); console.log(numdays);

    var expirationDate = result.addDays(numdays);

     end_date1 = new Date(expirationDate);
     var newdate = chgDateFormat(end_date1);
     $datepicker1.val(newdate);

     $("input").prop("disabled", false);  // enable all previously disabled inputs

     for( i=2; i< 11; i++) {
         var nextDate = result.addDays(i-1);
         if(nextDate <= expirationDate) {
             var date1 = new Date(nextDate);
             date1 = chgDateFormat(date1);
             var $nextDate = $("#date"+i);
             $nextDate.val(date1);
         }
         else {
             // disable other date fields
             var $nextDate = $("#date"+i);
             $("#date"+i).val('');
             $("#date"+i).prop("disabled", true);
         }
     }

});

function chgDateFormat(date) {
     var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
     var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
     var year = date.getFullYear();
     var newdate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day; 
     return newdate;
}
</script>
```